# Add tag to Tkinter PhotoImage

Tags: python, tkinter, tags, tkinter-photoimage

I'm writing a program that creates a new canvas item, with a specific image depending on a certain variable.
Here's an example of what I'm after, with *>>>>tag<<<<* representing (preferably a string) linked to one of those PhotoImages:

```
image = PhotoImage(file="File.png")
image_2 = PhotoImage(file="File_2.png")
output = >>>>tag<<<<
c.create_image(0, 0, image=output)
```

So far, I have been unable to find a way to link a PhotoImage item to a tag or some way of relating it to a different variable.
The only other way to do what I want to do would be to create a huge line of "if" statements which would be extremely time-consuming and unnecessary. So any method of tagging would be extremely helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need that? You can add a tag using `.create_image(..., tags=("tagname", ))`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, I was hoping to display multiple images using a single ```.create_image``` item, then use ```.itemconifg(image=)``` to quickly swap between images rather than creating a new frame for every image, then having to manually show and hide each frame with ```.itemconfig(state=)```.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas supports associating tags with a canvas item. For example, to add the tag "meta" to the image you would do something like this:

```
c.create_image(0, 0, image=output, tags=("meta",))
```

In addition to setting the `tags` option when creating an item, there are many methods on the canvas for working with tags. Though, almost all are just specializations of calling `addtag` with a special argument. For example, `addtag_above('foo', 'bar')` is the same as calling `addtag('foo', 'above', 'bar')`

- addtag
- addtag_above
- addtag_all
- addtag_below
- addtag_closest
- addtag_closest
- addtag_enclosed
- addtag_overlapping
- addtag_withtag

In addition, you can use the options `itemconfig` and `itemcget`.